# Derivatives of Euler products

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, euler-product

Suppose I have an Euler product absolutely convergent for $\sigma >1$ $$\mathcal Z_\mathbf z(s)=\prod _p\left (1-\frac {1}{2p^{s}}\left (\frac {1}{p^z}+\frac {1}{p^{z'}}\right )\right );$$ note $$\mathcal Z_\mathbf 0(s)=\frac {1}{\zeta (s)}.\hspace {10mm}(1)$$  I want to say something about the derivatives
$$
\left (\frac {d}{d\mathbf z}\right )^\mathbf D\Bigg |_{\mathbf z=0}\mathcal Z_\mathbf z(s) = \left (\frac {d}{dz}\right )^D \left (\frac {d}{dz'}\right )^{D'} \Bigg |_{z=z'=0}\mathcal Z_{z,z'}(s)
$$
and ideally link them to the derivatives of $\mathcal Z_\mathbf 0(s)$. Is that possible?

One thing I'm trying is: Define for squarefree $n$ $$a_\mathbf z(n):=\frac {1}{2^{\omega (n)}}\prod _{p|n}\left (\frac {1}{p^z}+\frac {1}{p^{z'}}\right )=\frac {1}{2^{\omega (n)}}\sum _{ml=n}\frac {1}{m^zl^{z'}}.$$ Then $$\mathcal Z_\mathbf z(s)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\mu (n)a_\mathbf z(n)}{n^s}=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\mu (n)}{n^s2^{\omega (n)}}\sum _{ml=n}\frac {1}{m^zl^{z'}}$$ so $$\mathcal Z_\mathbf 0(s)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\mu (n)d(n)}{n^s2^{\omega (n)}}=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {\mu (n)}{n^s}=\frac {1}{\zeta (s)}.$$ (This is obviously the same as (1) but I can differentiate the expressions in the derivations, and I guess I was hoping that matching $\log $ powers have equal coefficients, or something like that.)

Comment: Are $z,z'$ just the two complex components of the vector **z**?

Comment: And if so, what do you mean by the notation $d/d\mathbf z$?

Comment: yep, $\mathbf z=(z,z')$ and $(d/d\mathbf z)^\mathbf D$ is shorthand for $(d/dz)^D(d/dz')^{D'}$

Answer (score 1):

Proposed method: Begin with Faà di Bruno's formula for the high-order derivatives of a composition of two functions:
$$
\frac{d^n}{dz^n} h\bigl( g(z) \bigr) = \sum_{k=1}^n h^{(k)}(g(z)) B_{n,k}\bigl( g'(z),g''(z),\dots,g^{(n)}(z) \bigr),
$$
where the incomplete exponential Bell polynomials are defined to be
$$
B_{n,k}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{\substack{0\le m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n\le n \\ m_1+2m_2+\cdots+nm_n = n \\ m_1+m_2+\cdots+m_n=k}} \frac{n!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!} \biggl( \frac{x_1}{1!} \biggr)^{m_1} \biggl( \frac{x_2}{2!} \biggr)^{m_2} \cdots \biggl( \frac{x_n}{n!} \biggr)^{m_n},
$$
When applied with $h(u)=e^u$, this becomes
$$
\frac{d^n}{dz^n} e^{g(z)} = \sum_{k=1}^n e^{g(t)} B_{n,k}\bigl( g'(z),g''(z),\dots,g^{(n)}(z) \bigr) = e^{g(z)} B_n\bigl( g'(z),g''(z),\dots,g^{(n)}(z) \bigr).
$$
where the complete exponential Bell polynomial is
\begin{align*}
B_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k}(x_1,\dots,x_n) \\
&= \sum_{\substack{0\le m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n\le n \\ m_1+2m_2+\cdots+nm_n = n}} \frac{n!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!} \biggl( \frac{x_1}{1!} \biggr)^{m_1} \biggl( \frac{x_2}{2!} \biggr)^{m_2} \cdots \biggl( \frac{x_n}{n!} \biggr)^{m_n}.
\end{align*}
You can apply this with $g(\mathbf z) = \log \mathcal Z_\mathbf z(s)$ and then set $\mathbf z=0$; and you can also apply it with $g(s) = \log \mathcal Z_\mathbf 0(s)$. Compare the answers and see what happens....

Comment: Thanks for thinking about it!  Maybe I'm not seeing everything you're envisaging, but my objection would be: I already have a problem for the first derivatives (I don't know how they're linked even in this simple case, or is there something obvious I'm missing?) which we don't need the Bell polynomials for (one or two applications of the Chain Rule is manageable by hand). However your answer has still helped me, in particular considering the $\log $ of the product.

Comment: Isn't $\dfrac d{dz} \mathcal Z_{\mathbf z}(s) = Z_{\mathbf z}(s) \sum\limits_p \dfrac{\log p}{2p^{s+z}}$ and so $\dfrac d{dz} \mathcal Z_{\mathbf z}(s) \big|_{\mathbf z=\mathbf 0} =\dfrac12 \dfrac d{ds} \mathcal Z_{\mathbf 0}(s)$?

Comment: I get $d/dz\mathcal Z_\mathbf z(s)=\mathcal Z_\mathbf z(s)d/dz\sum _p\log (1-1/2p^s(1/p^z+1/p^{z'}))$, which seems different to your derivative (but it is $\approx $ to yours). (Or were you doing something else?)

Comment: Ah, I think I get it, let me try writing it up

Comment: Nope:D I guess I didn't get your last comment fully (I don't see that it's such a simple relation)

Comment: You're right, I did the chain rule part but not the whole thing. I agree that I don't see a simple relation even in the case of a single derivative. So maybe that's the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure... (doesn't it feel like the product really should be like $1/\zeta (s)$?)

Comment: Not really, to be honest. Look how complicated the multiplicative function is.